# C++ Create std::list in function and return through arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

How to correct return created std::list through function argument? Now, I try so:

```
bool DatabaseHandler::tags(std::list<Tag> *tags)
{
    QString sql = "SELECT * FROM " + Tag::TABLE_NAME + ";";
    QSqlQueryModel model;
    model.setQuery(sql);

    if(model.lastError().type() != QSqlError::NoError) {
        log(sql);
        tags = NULL;
        return false;
    }

    const int count = model.rowCount();

    if(count > 0)
        tags = new std::list<Tag>(count);
    else
        tags = new std::list<Tag>();
//some code

    return true;
}
```

After I can use it:

```
std::list<Tag> tags;
mDB->tags(&tags);
```

Now, I fix my function:

```
bool DatabaseHandler::tags(std::list<Tag> **tags)
{
    QString sql = "SELECT * FROM " + Tag::TABLE_NAME + ";";
    QSqlQueryModel model;
    model.setQuery(sql);

    if(model.lastError().type() != QSqlError::NoError) {
        log(sql);
        *tags = NULL;
        return false;
    }

    const int count = model.rowCount();

    if(count > 0)
        *tags = new std::list<Tag>(count);
    else
        *tags = new std::list<Tag>();

    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        auto record = model.record(i);
        Tag tag(record.value(Table::KEY_ID).toInt());
        (*tags)->push_back(tag);
    }

    return true;
}
```

It works but list return size 4 although loop executes only 2 iterations and empty child objects (if I just called their default constructor). The Tag class hasn't copy constructor.

Comment: Telling us what's `Tag` will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you passed an already instantiated list as a pointer to the function, there is no need to create another list.
In that sense, you question is pretty unclear. I'd suggest you read up a bit on pointers, references and function calls in general.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/

UPDATE: I still strongly suggest you read up on the mentioned topics, since you don't know these fundamental points.
Anyway, this is what you probably want to do (event though I would suggest using references, here is the solution with pointers):

```
bool someFunc(std::list<Tag> **tags) {
    // by default null the output argument
    *tags = nullptr;
    if (error) {
        return false;
    }

    // dereference tags and assign it the address to a new instance of list<Tag>
    *tags = new std::list<Tag>();
    return true
}


std::list<Tag> *yourList;
if (someFunc(&yourList)) {
    // then yourList is valid
} else {
   // then you had an error and yourList == nullptr
}
```

However, this is not idiomatic C++. Please read a modern book or tutorial.

Comment: I know that I can pass already initialized object's pointer as function argument but I want move a list initialization into function body.

Comment: Now, I can use double pointer in function argument and it works but list return size 4 althought I passed only two values. It crushes my brains.

Comment: Thank you! I made initialization out function but I very need to understand how to write this variant (I only start study C++).

Comment: And yet question... If I use initialization in function body I need to copy constructor for Tag class?

Answer (score 1):

Use a reference.

```
bool DatabaseHandler::tags(std::list<Tag>& tags);

std::list<Tag> tags;
mDB->tags(tags);
```

You'll have to change all the `->` to `.`, of course. Every operation done on the reference in the function will be done to the original `tags` list it was called with.

EDIT: If you want to create the list inside the function and return it, you have a couple options. The closest, I think, is to just return a list pointer, and return `nullptr` if the function fails.

```
//beware, pseudocode ahead
std::list<Tag>* DatabaseHandler::tags() //return new list
{
    if (success)
        return new std::list<Tag>(...); //construct with whatever
    else
        return nullptr; //null pointer return, didn't work
}

std::list<Tag> tags* = mDB->tags();
```

You could alternatively have it return an empty list instead, depending on how you want it to work. Taking a reference to a pointer would work the same way, too.

```
    bool DatabaseHandler::tags(std::list<Tag>*&); //return true/false

    std::list<Tag>* tags;
    mDB->tags(tags); //tags will be set to point to a list if it worked
```

Comment: I need to initialize list into function body.